# Хранение сложных структур данных в БД mysql

Tags: mysql

Прошу, помогите разобраться со сложившемся непониманием:
Предположим, необходимо создать бд для социальной сети. Есть сущность **User** с полями: id, ..., **messages** и поле **messages** имеет поля: text, createdAt и т.д. И сразу возникает вопрос: а как подобное хранить в mysql? Создавать отдельную таблицу **messages**  ощущается полностью нелогичным действием, ведь **messages** имеет неразрывную связь с **User** и, если мы удалим таблицу **User**, в существовании таблицы **messages** не будет какого-либо смысла. И тут возникает мысль: либо я не осознаю некоторую часть возможностей mysql, либо хранения данных в подобной структуре перекладываются на другие бд. И если истинно второе, то тогда возникает вопрос: разве есть проекты, где возможно избежать необходимости в хранении данных в таком виде? Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь поможет мне разобраться в недопонимании mysql, спасибо!

Comment: *Есть сущность User с полями: id, ..., messages и поле messages имеет поля: text, createdAt и т.д.* У сущности НЕТ полей. У сущности есть атрибуты. При этом атрибут сам может быть сущностью. Что и наблюдается для `message` - это самостоятельная сущность. Однозначно требующая отдельной таблицы. И существования связи в виде внешнего ключа. *если мы удалим таблицу User, в существовании таблицы messages не будет какого-либо смысла.* Давайте сразу рассматривать удаление всей БД тогда уж, чего мелочиться...

Comment: Если речь идёт о миллионах записей то я предпочёл бы какой-нибудь elasticsearch

Comment: @Akina, похоже на вечный спор. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Скорее похоже на неправильно выполненный анализ предметной области. Если он вообще выполнялся, конечно... О существовании ER-диаграммы я даже не говорю...

Comment: Вы сейчас в адекватности осознаете то, что я писал? Я лишь просил помочь мне разобраться с недопониманием бд. И пишу я это же не просто так: что будет, если я напишу в поисковике запрос - пособие mysql? CRUD, join и т.д. И на этом все! Вот у меня и сложилось недопонимание. Я новичок в этой области, понимаете? Я не могу с воздуха узнать о существовании каких-то диаграмм и вместо того, чтобы выражать высокомерие, вы могли подсказать мне о таких вещах. Мне кажется, что вы не туда пришли, если вы желаете конфликтов, а не помогать людям, то вам явно не следовало открывать мой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У баз данных есть свойство - нормализация. Нормализованной считается такая структура базы данных, которая удовлетворяет одной из 6 форм нормализации.

Подробнее про формы нормализации можно ознакомиться на русском [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/254773/) и [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0). На английском [здесь](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html)

Касаемо вашего случая - пользователь самостоятельная сущность. Сообщение пользователя условно самостоятельная сущность, так как сообщение действительно всегда должно быть привязано к какому-то пользователю.
Согласно формам нормализации для сообщения должна существовать своя таблица, как и для пользователя. Сущность сообщений должна иметь отношение вида многие-к-одному (ManyToOne), так как один пользователь может отправить множество сообщений, но в обратном направлении - невозможно.

Удалять же данные лучше никогда, чем хоть когда-нибудь. 
Если клиент желает удаления профиля (представим, что софт такое позволяет), то лучше

1. Добавить флаг в пользователя (быстрый вариант, но не самый хороший), который будет выставляться в true после удаления профиля и настроить работу софта так, чтобы учитывались только активные пользователи.
2. Добавить дополнительную сущность, которая будет хранить в себе событие удаления профиля - дату и время, причину, и т.д. (хороший вариант, соответствующий формам нормализации).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!